# Magnolia Blossom using Maven

Tags: maven-3, maven-jetty-plugin, maven-tomcat-plugin, magnolia

I am trying to get started with Magnolia Blossom using [this document](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Getting+started+with+Blossom).

I followed the steps (except ' Creating your own module' part) and was able to import the project in Eclipse.

I have also added the Jetty Maven plugin as described above.

While trying to run the web application user 'mvn:jetty:run', I am getting following exception in my command prompt :-

```
2013-11-25 14:38:58,804 INFO info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager : Loading  JCR
2013-11-25 14:38:58,805 ERROR info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager : Can't    load file: WEB-INF/config/default/repositories.xm
java.io.IOException: Can't load file: WEB-INF/config/default/repositories.xml
at info.magnolia.cms.util.ConfigUtil.getTokenizedConfigFile(ConfigUtil.java:105)
at       info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager.loadRepositories(DefaultRepositoryManager.     java:160)
at  info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager.init(DefaultRepositoryManager.java:85)
.
.
.

at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
2013-11-25 14:38:59,099 WARN info.magnolia.cms.util.ClasspathResourcesUtil : missing   file: D:\Softwares\maven-repo\info\magnolia\mag
magnolia-empty-webapp-5.1.war!\WEB-INF\classes
2013-11-25 14:38:59,169 WARN info.magnolia.cms.util.ClasspathResourcesUtil : missing   file: D:\my-projects\blossom\blossom-hw\blossom
es
2013-11-25 14:38:59,251 ERROR info.magnolia.cms.security.JCRSessionOp : failed to     retrieve repository config with config
javax.jcr.NoSuchWorkspaceException: config
at     info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager.getSystemSession(DefaultRepositoryManager. java:238)
at   info.magnolia.context.SystemRepositoryStrategy.internalGetSession(SystemRepositoryStrategy.java:56)
.
.
.
```

I am able to deploy and run the same war file using Tomcat Manager App. That hints that war being generated is correct.

Please help me to run the web app using Maven Jetty/Tomcat plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnolia fails to find the configuration files when you run it with jetty:run. Use instead jetty:run-war or jetty:run-exploded.